# How can i get this so i can input 2 different input

Tags: java, input

Just trying to get this so I can input 2 different types of input such as "accessories" and "a".

```
else if (tstart.equals("accessories"))
{

}
```

Comment: add another `else if`?

Comment: thanks for the advice however I want it so if I input "accessories" or "a" it will output the same output without adding another else if statement

Comment: `else if (tstart.equals("accessories") || tstart.equals("a"))`

Answer (score 0):

You can do:

```
else if(tstart.equals("accessories") || tstart.equals("a"){
//Remaining code
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
else if (tstart.equals("accessories") || tstart.equals("a"))
    {
        for(int i=0; i < electrical.length ; i++)
                sum = sum + electrical[i];

        double average = sum / electrical.length;
        System.out.printf("Average value of array elements is : £%.2f",+ average);
   }
```